# Convex Combination Generalized to Infinite Sums

Tags: sequences-and-series, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

I'm independently studying Boyd & Vandenberghe's *Convex Optimization* and came across the following statement discussing convex combinations of infinite terms.

> The idea of a convex combination can be generalized to include
>   infinite sums, integrals, and, in the most general form, probability
>   distributions. Suppose $\theta_1, \theta_2, \dots$ satisfy
>
> $$\begin{align} \theta_i &\geq 0 \\ i &= 1, 2, \dots \\
> \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \theta_i &= 1 \end{align}$$
>
> and $x_1, x_2, \dots \in C$, where $C \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ is convex. Then
>
> $$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \theta_i x_i \in C$$ if the series converges.

My first question is$\dots$ what mathematical concept or proof enables us to generalize the definition of convex combination from a finite $k$ to $k = \infty$? Previously in the book, the definition of convex combination was simply introduced as

> A point of the form $\theta_1 x_1 + \dots + \theta_k x_k$, where
>   $\theta_1 + \dots + \theta_k = 1$ and $\theta_i \geq 0$, $i = 1, \dots, k$ is a convex combination of the points $x_1, \dots, x_k$.

My second question is$\dots$ why is it necessary that the series converge? Shouldn't the fact that $C$ is convex guarantee that the infinite sum $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \theta_i x_i \in C$ since $C$ is a convex set and convex sets are closed under convex combination?

Thank you for taking the time to read this lengthy question!

Comment: The real line is a convex set, but if $\theta_n = c/n^2$ (where $c$ is chosen to ensure $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \theta_n = 1$) and $x_n = n$ then the series does not converge and thus does not belong to the real line.

Comment: @vadim123  No, we're starting with the usual definition of a convex set and showing that under this definition one can take convext combinations of an infinite number of points as long as the sum converges.  angryavian's example shows the sum might fail to converge.

Comment: Search for CS-closed and CS-compact, where CS stands for *convex series*. See, e.g., https://www.cambridge.org/core/services/aop-cambridge-core/content/view/S0305004100050933

Comment: I'm curious about the extension to integrals, does anyone know a reference for this?