# How to generalize the convex combination to infinite sum?

Tags: analysis, convex-analysis

Suppose $\theta_1, \theta_2, \cdots$ satisfy $\theta_i \geq 0, i=1,2, \cdots,\sum_{i=1}^\infty \theta_i =1 ,$ and $x_1,x_2,\cdots \in C$, where $C\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is convex. Then $\sum_{i=1}^\infty \theta_i x_i \in C$. I am confused that it may need to suppose C to be closed. Right?

Comment: Assuming $C$ is closed is sufficient to get your conclusion.  But there are convex sets that are not closed, yet also satisfy your conclusion.  For example the open interval $(0,1)$ in $\mathbb R^1$.  Do all convex sets, closed or not, satisfy your conclusion?  Studying the example $(0,1)$ may help inanswering that.

Comment: Yeah. If C Is closed. I can obtain my conclusion. But I wonder not all convex set has this property. It may need some condtion weaker than clsed, right?

Comment: @dragonleave [This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3128234/869647) may be useful to you?